# I am new to flutter, and would like to open google map How do I fix the error The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, url-launcher

```
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

class MapsUtils {
  MapsUtils._();

  //latitude longitude
  static Future<void> openMapWithPosition(
      double latitude, double longitude) async {
    String googleMapUrl =
        "https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=$latitude,$longitude";

    if (await canLaunchUrl(googleMapUrl)) {
      await launchUrl(googleMapUrl);
    } else {
      throw "Could not open the map.";
    }
  }

  //text address
  static Future<void> openMapWithAddress(String fullAddress) async {
    String query = Uri.encodeComponent(fullAddress);
    String googleMapUrl =
        "https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=$query";

    if (await canLaunchUrl(googleMapUrl)) {
      await launchUrl(googleMapUrl);
    } else {
      throw "Could not open the map.";
    }
  }
}
```

[The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1oiZ.png)

I am on VS Code and once I finish writing that code this is the error(s) I am getting. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The small mistake you've did is stored url as a String and passing that to LaunchUrl.
The following changes you've to do...

```
     ..... // Above Code
     final Uri googleMapUrl = Uri.parse('https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=$query');
     // Add your own below code.......
```

Comment: Thank you Rohan Jariwala. This solves the error, however I can not open google maps instead throws an error implemented on the code "Could not open the map".  Does this mean the code is working perfectly fine and the issue is on google side or network issues?

Comment: Using `Uri.parse` will work, but it's generally better to use the default `Uri` constructor and let the class handle building the full URL string than to construct the URL string manually.

Comment: Can you show me what your `$query` look like

Comment: @Abion47 yeah of course we can do that way. Moha Nkossie\  give it a try